# jQuery textarea draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

OI have a simple problem with jQuery draggable with a textarea.

I have to insert a textarea into a div draggable but the area of textarea isn't draggable, only border! I have tried to disable textarea but nothing.
I would like to have a textarea NOT editable but draggable / resizable.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="drag-item item-txt txt-static" id="1>" style="position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; top:50px; left:10px; z-index:50;">
     <textarea disabled style=" width:98px; height:48px;">Some text</textarea>
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
                $('.drag-item').draggable({
                    snap        : true,
                    cursor      : "move",
                    delay       : 100,
                    scroll      : false,
                    containment : "parent",
                    stop: function (e, ui){
                       //some code
                    },
                    drag: function(e, ui){
                       //some code
                    }
                }).resizable({
                    containment : "parent",
                    stop: function(e, ui) {
                        var width = ui.size.width;
                        var height = ui.size.height;
                        var hereDrag = this;

                        if($(hereDrag).find('textarea').length > 0){
                            $(hereDrag).find('textarea').css('width', width - 10);
                            $(hereDrag).find('textarea').css('height', height - 10);
                        }
                    },
                    resize: function(e, ui){
                       //some code
                    }
                })
```

How can I make this textarea not editable but draggable and resiazable in all the area e not onyl to the border?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/VyL7k/1/)**

Try this,
just add an id attribute to your textarea `id="text"` and add an attribute `cancel:"text,"` in your `draggable()`

### html

```
<div class="drag-item item-txt txt-static" id="1>" style="position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; top:50px; left:10px; z-index:50;">
     <textarea disabled style=" width:98px; height:48px;" name="text" id="text">Some text</textarea>
</div>
```

### code

```
$(function () {
    $('.drag-item').draggable({
                    snap        : true,
                    cursor      : "move",
                    delay       : 100,
                    scroll      : false,
                    cancel: "text",
                    containment : "parent",
                   drag: function(e, ui){
                       //some code
                    }
                }).resizable({
                    containment : "parent",
                    stop: function(e, ui) {
                        var width = ui.size.width;
                        var height = ui.size.height;
                        var hereDrag = this;

                        if($(hereDrag).find('textarea').length > 0){
                            $(hereDrag).find('textarea').css('width', width - 10);
                            $(hereDrag).find('textarea').css('height', height - 10);
                        }
                    },
                    resize: function(e, ui){
                       //some code
                    }
                })

});
```

Hope this helps,thank you

Comment: I cannot assign a div to the textarea because is created dynamically every time, but seems work without id

Comment: if you cannot add 'id' to it just set the attribute cancel:" ",  attribute,hope this helps

Comment: specify cancel:" ", will be enough

Answer (score 5):

While the accepted answer works for this specific situation the reasoning is simply wrong. So for anyone wanting to understand how this works:

The jQuery UI draggables `cancel` option is a jQuery selector, which specifies elements on which it should *not* be possible to start a drag operation.

According to the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel) it defaults to `input,textarea,button,select,option`.

So all that is needed to allow dragging on a `textarea` inside the draggable is to supply any `cancel` option that does *not* include `textarea`.

```
$('.drag-item').draggable({cancel: ''});
```

or

```
$('.drag-item').draggable({cancel: 'input,button,select,option,.undraggable'});
```

The accepted answer sets `id="text"` on the `textarea` and sets `cancel: "text"` on the `draggable`. What this really means is that any `<text></text>` element inside the draggable `div` will cancel the drag operation, while dragging will work on any other element - including the `textarea`. The `id` attribute is entirely irrelevant in this case.

If one wanted to *cancel* dragging (not *enable* dragging) on a specific element with an `id="text"` attribute, then the correct value for the `cancel` option would be the jQuery selector `#text`.

Comment: Exactly what I was wondering - but the important message is that "cancel" has some default values set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
<div class="item-txt txt-static" id="1" style="position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; top:50px; left:10px; z-index:50;">
     <textarea class="drag-item" disabled style="width:98px; height:48px;">Some text</textarea>
</div>
```

The text area was not draggable since you have given draggable property to the div only.

Comment: I have to make the div draggable because I have many div in a container, I can't assign the draggable to the textarea directly

Comment: Okay so you need to drag div as well as text area along with it.? But there are other html contents in the div too other than the textarea?